# When I design an image in Photoshopt to post as a header in CSS, the resolution messes up

Tags: html, css, image, header, resolution

I am quite new to html and CSS, my problem is that each time I post a header image on my HTML file it doesn't fit across the screen. I try width: 100%; but then it messes up the resolution. Here is my current code:

HTML -

```
<div id="header">
        <h1><img src="images/headings/titleheader.png"
        width="800" height="150" alt="Munsterberg Designs" border="0" /></h1>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
#header {
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  url(../images/headings/titleheader.png);
}
```

Is there a way to take my image that is 760x150 to fit across the screen no matter the resolution of someones monitor?

Comment: Short answer: no. If you want your image to span the entire width, it needs to be scaled (how much it "messes up the resolution" is due to the viewer's browser *only*). Long answer: with Javascript you could check the view window width and select a 'most appropriate' sized image, and you would supply a good range of sizes.

Comment: Make header background image 1920x150 and put image content on center, that way you gonna keep the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `<img>` is HTML tag for placing an image into your HTML page/document
2. "background-image" is a CSS property. You place an image as background into a `<div>` for eg. not into a `<img>`

   They are COMPLETELY different. Don't confuse both!

If you want the  image as 100% width you should put it as 100% at image and header both, and remove "height" property, that's what is breaking the resolution:

```
#header{
   width:100%; /* put header as 100% */
}

#header img
{
    width:100%;  /* put header's image as 100% */
}

<div id="header">
        <h1>
          <img src="images/headings/titleheader.png" alt="Munsterberg Designs" border="0" />
        </h1>
    </div>
```

If you see, I'm not using "background" or "background-image" because I don't want a background image , I have the actual image at `<img>` HTML tag

Now if you want the `background` css approach check for @mdesdev answer and remove `<img>` tag from your HTML document, you need to choose only one way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header">

</div>

#header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px; /* For demo purpose */
  background: #000 url(../images/headings/titleheader.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the image within the div in the HTML.

```
<div id="header></div>
```

In the CSS, indicate the height and width.  To get it to fill the entire width, try using background-size: cover

```
#header { height: 150px;
          background: black url("../images/headings/titleHeader.png") no-repeat;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;}
```

This is untested but it should be something similar to this.

[This link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) should also help you